# Change fontstyle on PivotField Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, pivot

I have a code that builds my pivottable, and I want to set one of the fields as italic but i cant figure out how.

The code I have is like this from the begining:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Laddsida").PivotFields("Work hrs")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 6
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
.Name = "Uppskattad arbetad tid"
End With
```

Have tried with this:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Laddsida").PivotFields("Work hrs")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 6
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
.font.Italic = True
.Name = "Uppskattad arbetad tid"
End With
```

But get the following error:

> Run-time error"438":
>
> Object doesn't support this porperty or method

After your help I've managed to get this far, but the `RowRange` only affects the first one as in this image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfMZn.png)

Comment: `.Font` is [not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield) part of the properties known to the `PivotFields` object model.

Comment: Well so I've figured, do you know a way to perhaps make it work any way? Some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment: `.Font` is not part of the properties known to the PivotFields object model. You could however use the [`PivotField.DataRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.datarange) which will return a `Range` object, which in it's turn does support `.Font`; for example:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("????") 'Name of your sheet
ws.PivotTables("Laddsida").PivotFields("Work hrs").DataRange.Font.Italic = True

End Sub
```

---

As per your comment, I think you got headers in your row, also called a [`RowRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.rowrange). We can use this `Range` object to find your specific target header:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("????") 'Name of your sheet
Dim cl As Range

Set cl = ws.PivotTables("Laddsida").RowRange.Find("Work hrs")
If Not cl Is Nothing Then
    cl.Font.Italic = True
End If

End Sub
```

---

And as per your latest comment, it appears you got multiple headers that have the same value, so you might want to use `.FindNext`:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("????") 'Name of your sheet
Dim cl As Range, rw As Long

With ws.PivotTables("Laddsida").RowRange
    Set cl = .Find("Work hrs")
    If Not cl Is Nothing Then
        rw = cl.Row
        Do
            cl.Font.Italic = True
            Set cl = .FindNext(cl)
        If cl Is Nothing Then GoTo DoneFinding
        Loop While cl.Row <> rw
    End If
DoneFinding:
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That's a great soloution, it solves my problem but not the way i thought!! It only affects the numbers, not the text. I want "Work hrs" to be in italic, but perhaps that to much to demand...

Comment: Are you talking about headers? @SebastianBoström

Comment: Perhaps... I',m pretty new to this so haven't got the correct terminology, but to the far left of the pivottable i have my list of "names" for the values i want to display, and it is one of the names in that list that I want to have in ```Italic```

Comment: I think I understand that you got `RowRange` headers. I will include an option to find your specific header. @SebastianBoström

Comment: It works, but only on the first one, I've added an image to the post

Comment: Right, in your case, you got multiple of the same headers, so we would need `FindNext`. See last update @SebastianBoström

Comment: You my friend are amazing! Thank you!